# Reference to nonexistent group in regex

Tags: regex, perl

This code opens a log file (csv) and takes some data from it. For example, here's a line from that file:

```
m/557,181, f2,20140
```

Here's the code:

```
open(LOG, '<',"$data_file") or die "can't open LOG $!\n";

while (my $line = <LOG>) {
print "$line\n";
($re,$sure,$ker,$ste) = split ($line, ',');

}

close LOG;
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Reference to nonexistent group in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/557,181, f\2<-- HERE,20140
```

Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
split(',', $line)
```

not

```
split($line, ',').
```

Answer (score 4):

```
($re,$sure,$ker,$ste) = split (',', $line);
```

which is really

```
($re,$sure,$ker,$ste) = split (/,/, $line);
```

as `split` separator is always regex (`' '` is special case)